# Having one input field auto update another, and vice versa (probably using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'm not that experienced in JavaScript, so need som help with a project.

I have a form of, among other things, 3 input text fields (let's call them A, B and C). I need the user to only be able to type into either A+B *OR* C. So is it possible to make a form field inactive, once the user clicks in another (and vice versa).

Would really appreciate any help. My guess is this needs t be done in JavaScript.

Comment: this could be done using javascript but could more easily done if you want to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can write a javascript for this which is bind as follow

```
<script>
function fun(ele){
var elea=document.getElementById('a');
var eleb=document.getElementById('b');
var elec=document.getElementById('c');
if (ele.id='a' &&(eleb.length==0 || elec.length==0))
{
      this.readonly=false;
}
if (ele.id='b' && (elea.length==0 || elec.length==0))
{
       this.readonly=false;
}
if (ele.id='c' && (elea.length==0 || eleb.length==0))
{
       this.readonly=false;
}

}
</script>
<input type="text" id="a" onfocus="fun(this)" readonly="true"/>
<input type="text" id="b" onfocus="fun(this)" readonly="true"/>
<input type="text" id="c" onfocus="fun(this)" readonly="true"/>
```

you can also bind the events dynamically instead of inline see [Four Ways Javascript Binding Event Listeners](http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/four-ways-javascript-binding-event-listeners/)

Comment: yes you can write js every where in html page just you have to enclose it in <script> tag

Comment: I meant inline event binding. This is not semantic code. This is valid BTW

Comment: Highly inefficient code and I think you need a .value in there

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<input class="onlyone" id="first" />
<input class="onlyone" id="second" />
<input class="onlyone" id="third" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.onlyone').addEventListener('click', function(){
if(this.getAttribute('disabled') != 'disabled'){ // check if it was disabled before

   for(var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll('.onlyone').length; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll('.onlyone')[i].setAttribute('disabled, 'disabled'); //disable em all
   }

   this.removeAttribute('disabled'); //enable this one
}
}, false);
```